# Android: Populating a ListView with a variable number of custom layout items; java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface, classcastexception

I am writing an application that randomly generates basic details of NPCs and other things for RPGs, this Activity is a settings page for modifying the number, names, and probabilities of the different character races for the purposes of randomly generating these characters.

My layout would have a ListView, each item having a TextView displaying the name of a race, and an EditText with a float value to input the probability of the race appearing upon generation of a new character. I am having trouble making this layout happen, despite its (perceived?) relative simplicity, as I am quite new to the Android platform as well as Java in general.

-- FIXED --
Upon starting the activity I get a java.lang.ClassCastException: Integer. The debugger points me to lines in precompiled resource jars, and I am unsure of what exactly a classCastException with the variable e means, where would that get passed in, if I didn't write an exception handler myself?
-- FIXED --

I have a new error that deals with JSONArrays, you can see in my code that I declare null String[] and float[] arrays, then attempt to fill them within a try/catch using methods that pull JSONArrays as strings from the SharedPreferences and put values into the given arrays. Declaring them null gives me a NullPointer exception when I assign values to it in my for loop below, and declaring them inside the try/catch gives them scope only for the try/catch block statement.

I appreciate your consideration of my predicament, and any help you can offer.

This is my code:

```
import org.json.JSONException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GeneratorSettingsNPCRaceProbsActivity extends RandomGeneratorActivity
{
/** Called when the activity is first created. 
 * @throws JSONException */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings_npc_race_probs);

    ListView settingsList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView_menu);
    //Sets up a list of races with their corresponding probabilities in a text field. In the future,
    //one will be able to edit a text field an commit changes to set the probabilities for each race.
    //Perhaps I will implement a way to add custom races to the list.

    //Finds current profile
    SharedPreferences appSettings = getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
    String currentProfile = appSettings.getString("CurrentProfile", DEFAULT_PROFILE);
    //Gets races and probabilities from current SharedPreferences profile
    SharedPreferences profileSettings = getSharedPreferences(currentProfile, MODE_PRIVATE);
    String[] races = null;
    float[] raceProbs = null;
    try {
        races = getProfileRaces(currentProfile);
        raceProbs = getProfileRaceProbabilities(currentProfile);
    } catch (JSONException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

    //Puts the races and raceProbs into a RaceItem array
    RaceItem[] raceItems = new RaceItem[races.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < races.length; i++)
    {
        raceItems[i].raceName = races[i];
        raceItems[i].raceProb = raceProbs[i];
    }

    Context context = this;

    final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
              (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    ArrayAdapter<RaceItem> adaptMenu = new ArrayAdapter<RaceItem>(context, android.R.layout.expandable_list_content)
            {
                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
                {
                    View row;
                    if (convertView == null) {
                        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_npc_race_probs_item, null);
                    }
                    else {
                        row = convertView;
                    }

                    TextView tv1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                    tv1.setText(getItem(position).raceName);

                    EditText et1 = (EditText) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
                    et1.setText(String.valueOf(getItem(position).raceProb));

                    return row;
                }
            };

            settingsList.setAdapter(adaptMenu);
}
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the code for the RandomGeneratorActivity class please? In particular line 107 would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks!
I fixed the error in Line 107 (I just type Float instead of float, so it didn't cast something correctly, whoops. My new error has been edited in.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure you put a try\catch around the place in the code that the exception is occurring (you may be swallowing the actual exception).

The exception is pointing to a place in the code where you are trying to populate a value with something that is inconsistent (probably trying to put a String in an int value).

You didn't include the complete stack in this question (a good way to get this is to open a command prompt, and type: adb logcat - which should clearly point to the specific place in your Android code that is erroring out).

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my post to include the errors from LogCat, but it won't let me retrieve the last 11 error messages. I hope the relevant errors are the ones that show up.

It's not a casting error, I don't think, as my code (I think) is pretty clear about what variables are going where, and none of the assignment lines are highlighted.